# When I click back and forward Buton of browser all of my dynamically created PartialView get disappered

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I can create multiple `Partialviews` in my view

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model Opto.Models.Recipe

....
 
<div id="Far" class="tab-pane active card-body">
                            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                            <div class="row form-group">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="text-left" dir="ltr">
                                        <partial name="RecipeFarSighted.cshtml" Model="Model.FarSighted" />
                                    </div>
                                    <hr />
                                    <div class="text-center" dir="rtl">
                                        <div id="FarSightedBillsSection">
                                            @*FarSightedBills will be created here by javascript*@
                                        </div>
                                        <a onclick="AddBill('far')" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="~/images/Plus.png" width="25" height="25" /></a>
                                        <br /><br />
                                        @if (!Model.FarSighted.Share)
                                        {
                                            <div class="form-group row form-check">
                                                <label class="form-check-label col">
                                                    <input asp-for="FarSighted.Share" type="checkbox"> عدم دریافت عینک
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>
...
@section Scripts{
        <script>
        var farIndex = 0;
        var farRealCount = 0;

function AddBill(type)
        {
                tag = "<div id='farSightedBill" + farIndex + "' ><a onclick=\"RemovePartial('far'," + farIndex + ")\" style='cursor: pointer'><img src='/images/Minus.png' width='25' height='25' /></a><h4><a onclick=\"$('#farSighted" + farIndex + "').collapse('toggle')\" style='cursor: pointer' data-target='#farSighted" + farIndex + "' id='farBillTitle" + farIndex + "' > عینک دائمی " + (farRealCount + 1) + "</a ></h4 > <br /><div class='collapse' id='farSighted" + farIndex + "'></div></div > ";
                $.get('/Glasses/DisplayFarBill?index=' + farIndex +
                            '&packFactor=' + '@(Model.FarSighted?.PackFactor)' + '&lenseCover=' + '@(Model.FarSighted?.LenseCover)',
                            function (partial) {
                                $('#FarSightedBillsSection').append(tag);
                                $('#farSighted' + farIndex).append(partial);
                                $('#farSighted' + farIndex).collapse('show');
                                //aaa(farIndex);
                                farIndex++;
                                farRealCount++
                            });
}
</script>
}
```

when I click the Back button of the browser and then forward, all my partial views will be disappeared. how can I solve this?
and when I go to submit action method in the controller for validation and there are some errors in it, when it goes back to view there are no parts in it, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,the Back and Forward button is used for navigating through visited Web pages.And it may uses BFCache,it will cache the whole page including jquery(Source code).And the partial view you added will not shown after Back,Forward click is because it is added by jquery.jquery will change the html code,but will not change the source code.When you click Back,Forward button,browser will reload the Source code,and render it to html code.If you want to show the partial view,you can only add them directly like this in your code:

```
<div class="text-left" dir="ltr">
       <partial name="RecipeFarSighted.cshtml" Model="Model.FarSighted" />
</div>
```